# How to load json data in expandable listview group and child in android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery

i want to create groups and childs in expandable listview from json in android?.how to add the json data to expandable listview group and child item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom adapter class to create expandable list view. Create a new class file called ExpandableListAdapter.java and extend this from BaseExpandableListAdapter. This class provides required methods to render such listview.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
 }

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
 }

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
 }

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
     }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
 }

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
 }

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
 }

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
 }

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
 }

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
     }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
 }

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
 }

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Follow this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/